# How can I find the right API to connect my Actuate motion simulator chair software to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my first time trying to find an API. Should I be successful I will then need to figure out how to use it.

I want to run a VR immersive experience on an oculus quest which a person wears while sitting in the motion simulator, I want the movement of a boat in the VR headset to correspond with the movement of the chair.

The software for the chair I have is called Actuate motion v1.0.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their website it says they have a "C API" (Which I can't find online documentation) but they aslo mention they have a unity plugin you can use for your game. I would use their plugin before attempting their api.